# SOAP web service returns string instead of xml

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I have a SOAP based web service. When I call a web service method from .net or java it returns the xml string. But when I call the method from PHP script it returns string.

Below is my PHP script:

```
<?php
   $client = new SoapClient("http://mydomain/services/transaction?wsdl");
   $result = $client->ProductOnHand(array('username'=>'myusername', 'Password'=>'mypassword', 'delatdate' => '17/06/2015 18:00:00'));
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
?>
```

If I print the `$result` as `var_dump($result);` it shows as xml, and if print as `echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);` it pints as string. So I am unable to parse it. Please suggest

Comment: `<xs:element name="ProductOnHandResponse"><xs:com...`  - this is result? why it is not xml?

Comment: this is namespace, but you can use simplexml or DomDocument  methods with setting prefix to work with such xml

Comment: @splash58 I tried for that. but cant set prefix xml tags, and one more doubt is how it is getting in XML in .net and java?

Comment: i can show how to work with it in php only. If it will be helpful for you...

Comment: https://eval.in/406007

Comment: @splash58 where to specify the wsdl URL in your coding, You are assigining the $str variable with the function present in WSDL, how a SOAP web service URL, will be loaded?

Comment: from where do you take the output `<xs:element name="Product...` ?

Comment: @splash58 I am taking output from $client = new SoapClient("http://mydomain/services/transaction?wsdl");

Comment: this $client put indtead of $str

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84297/discussion-between-version-beta-and-splash58).